# How to create a matplotlib figure,without opening a window

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like my code to generate and save a graph of its results, but I do not want to see a window with those results being plotted as my code runs. The lines of code where this happens are:

```
    self.acc_fig = plt.figure(1) # Create figure
    self.acc_fig.clf()           # Ensure fresh start
```

However, when the call to clf is made, a blank window opens on my screen. How do I not have this window open up,while still ensuring I can get afresh figure object, that I can call `savefig` when it's time to save my results?

Note: Repeating this procedure on the next day showed the window opened when the figure was created. I don't know if I was spectacularly unobservant when stepping through this code the first time with my debugger, or if there was some odd randomness in the interaction between my debugger, matplotlib & myself. Either way, it led me to a working answer...

Comment: Afaik, `clf()` in itself does not generate a window. Anything else you are doing there?

Comment: @Mr.T - No. That's what puzzles me. I've literally tracked this down with my debugger and see the window open as a step from the first line to the second. Though, consistent with your understanding, this does not happen when I open a python interpretter and just type in import .....; x=plt.figure(1);x.clf()

Comment: You did not accidentally redefine `clf()` by any chance? Can you provide a code sample that reproduces this behavior? Does this happen with different backends? Your system specs might also be of interest for people who actually know things about matplotlib.

Comment: @Mr.T - Pretty certain I haven't redefined clf. It's not a variable name I tend to use. I'll have to look into getting isolated code to reproduce this. Right now, I'm testing the rest of this code under a deadline, and though I don't like the windows, I can live with them

Comment: So, not reproducible the next day?

Comment: @Mr.T - Was reproducible, just not at the same line of code (i.e. at plt.figure, instead of fig.clf). Actively controlling the 'interactive' flag can both reproduce and solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that seems to be working for me is to ensure `matplotlib`'s interactive mode is turned off. I did this with the following line of code:

```
 plt.ioff()
```

The same result can be achieved with

```
 matplotlib.rcParams['interactive'] = False
```